# Prevent form rerendering in conrolled react inputs

Tags: html, reactjs

I am new to React.js and recently I learned about controlled inputs in React.

**Code:**

Here's a sample implementation that I made:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MyForm = () => {

    console.log('rendered');  // Line 5
    const [text1, setText1] = useState('');
    const [text2, setText2] = useState('');

    const onSubmit = (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log(text1, text2);
    }

    return (<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={text1} onChange={ev => setText1(ev.target.value)} />
        <input type="text" value={text2} onChange={ev => setText2(ev.target.value)} />
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>);
};
```

**Problem:**

Performance.

Above implementation works correctly, but I noticed that every time one of the field changes, `console.log('rendered');` at line 5 is called again, and the entire form seems to be re-rendered. I guess that this could cause some problem especially for more advanced forms with many input fields and heavy pre-processing, etc. Ideally only the field that has changed should be re-rendered.

So I was wondering if my understanding of controlled inputs and form is okay. If not what is more scalable way of implementing this?

Comment: The only way to avoid re-rendering is by using uncontrolled inputs. There's one good form library doing this, react-hook-form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the state changes, the component will re-render. this is normal. if you dont want that, you need to "export" your input fields to new components with their own state, but then you have to somehow `ref` these components back to your parent `form` component in order to get their current values when you are going to submit the form.

Check [this link](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/react-using-refs-with-the-useref-hook-884ed25b5c29) on how to use `ref`, but I think that the form should be way too heavy in order for you to consider such a senario of creating for each input its own state in order to avoid parent component re-rendering on every input change, or even change to uncontrolled component, which is not usually recommended.